# jquery serialize and $.post and receiving incomplete array on serverside

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

the jquery :

```
$("#btnSaveForm").click(function(){
...
$.post('../optional/setup/processItemcn.php', $("#FormTemplate").serialize(), function(data) {
     alert(data);
});
...
});
```

the php with form :

```
<form id="FormTemplate" class="FormTemplate">
  <input type="text" name="kode_item[]" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="kode_item[]" value="2" />
  <input type="text" name="kode_item[]" value="3" />
  .
  .
  <input type="text" name="kode_item[]" value="197" />
</form>
```

the php on serverside :

```
$ID = $_POST["kode_item"];
$count = count($ID);   
echo "$count";
```

I' am trying to send all array data from the form to the serverside using jquery post and serialize.
I have total items array of kode_item = 197 items, but after sending it to serverside and then I check and echo it from server side the result of $count = 167 items. that's why I cannot update data that related to kode_item > 167 because it will not processed on serverside. anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Please show the output of `print_r($ID)`.

Comment: alert($("#FormTemplate input[type=text]").length); also

Comment: Any empty fields (no value) in it?

Comment: code is tested with 200 entry also tested by sending empty value but counting is always correct you must miss-spell somewhere.. look deep-inside

Comment: @str the result of print_r($ID) is:  Array([0]=>1 [1]=>2 [2]=>3 ... [166]=>167)

Comment: @Akam trying to `alert($("#FormTemplate input[type=text]").length);` the result is 788, also trying `alert($("#FormTemplate input[name=kode_item[]]").length);` the result is 197.

Comment: I tested with 160 item array and everything is fine, the serverside also processed 160 item of array data, then trying with 170 item but the serverside still process just 167 item.....is there a limitation/maximun array to send with `$.post` and serialize maybe ?

Comment: can you show your real example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is come up from my webhosting technician.

The array data that send from form to the serverside is getting too long, then.. [suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) limiting the array data that will be sended.

This way work for me. Adding this two line to php.ini:

```
suhosin.post.max_vars = 1500
suhosin.request.max_vars = 1500
```

Answer (score 1):

try checking if you have the correct settings in your php.ini

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 8M
```

Comment: have checking my php.ini `post_max_size = 80M` already change to 8M then restart the apache services and nothing change...and...also have trying to change `max_execution_time = 1000` but still nothing change...

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue but didn't found a solution and after reading jQuery documentation I got an idea.

You can use `.serializeArray()` instead of using just `.serialize()` and playing with php.ini file. Here is the code I used in my project.

```
jQuery('.modal').on('click','.saveFeature',function(){ 

        var form = jQuery('#featureForm').serializeArray();
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({
            data:{
                csrf_name:jQuery('input[name="csrf_name"]').val()
            }
        });
        var url = "<?php echo 'product/features/'.$pid;?>";
        jQuery.post(url,{form}, function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        } );
    });
```

After submitting the form, you will get data in below format.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => csrf_name
        [value] => 3802b11296d42e602533bf266bb800bd
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => title
        [value] => kjhkjh
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => title_icon
        [value] => fa fa-heart
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => icon_color
        [value] => #a81616
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => icon_bg_color
        [value] => #662f2f
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => description
        [value] => testb
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => box_bg_color
        [value] => #bd2222
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [name] => box_bttm_bg
        [value] => #a61e1e
    )

)
```

Handing post data in back end, I'm using CodeIgniter Framework. Organize that post data in `key=>value` format so that it will be easy to store the data.

```
$arry = $this->input->post('form');
    $post = [];
    //check if this is not empty and is array
    if(!empty($arry) && is_array($arry)){
        //iterate over post data and organize array in key value format.
        foreach($arry as $ar) 
        {
            $post[$ar['name']] = $ar['value'];
        }
    }

    $data = [
        'pid' => $pid,
        'title' => $post['title'],
        'icon' => $post['title_icon'],
        'icon_color' => $post['icon_color'],
        'icon_bg_color' => $post['icon_bg_color'],
        'description' => $post['description'],
        'box_bg_color' => $post['box_bg_color'],
        'box_bttm_color' => $post['box_bttm_bg'],
    ];

    $this->db->insert(TBL_PRODUCT_FEATURES, $data);
```

Correct me if I'm wrong; I just shared my idea to solve this problem.